# In a GraphQL server, what is the best practice for triggering a subscription event from data received that needs to be parsed first?

Tags: graphql

Example:

I receive data in a string that needs to be parsed first, for example an IoT message.

I can create a mutation for that no problem, I'm just storing a string in a DB, however, based on **what** was in the string, I then want to save the data of the different types parsed, so I will have a switch statement in the resolver.

If I save the new types directly to the DB, they will not trigger a subscription.

If I save via calling the type's mutation (so calling a mutation within a mutation of the same schema), then it will trigger a subscription in my application, which is the desired effect.

Is this bad practice? Is there a better, recommended way of doing this?

Comment: That depends entirely on the server framework that you are using. I'm sure the event to refresh the subscription can also be fired manually, without using a mutation - in the mutation it just is included by default.

Comment: @Bergi doh yeah I should've probably thought of that! I'll check, thank you!